# Fix error setting custom ios font

Tags: objective-c, ios5, xcode4.5

I'm trying to set a custom font with an appearance proxy.

```
[[UILabel appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{
    UITextAttributeFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"PT Sans Narrow" size:10.0]
}];
```

I've added the ttf to my project, and confirmed that the font name is correct.

XCode gives me this error:

```
2012-11-27 02:04:00.002 dashboard-mock[17093:11303] -[_UIAppearance setTitleTextAttributes:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x712a1c0
2012-11-27 02:04:00.002 dashboard-mock[17093:11303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_UIAppearance setTitleTextAttributes:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x712a1c0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1c92012 0x10cfe7e 0x1d1d4bd 0x1c81bbc 0x1c8194e 0x2aec 0x147b7 0x14da7 0x15fab 0x27315 0x2824b 0x19cf8 0x1beddf9 0x1bedad0 0x1c07bf5 0x1c07962 0x1c38bb6 0x1c37f44 0x1c37e1b 0x157da 0x1765c 0x28cd 0x27f5)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are using [`-setTitleTextAttributes`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Uikit/reference/UIBarItem_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIBarItem/setTitleTextAttributes:forState:) with label while it is [`UINavigationBar`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationBar_Class/) function

```
if([[UINavigationBar appearance] respondsToSelector:@selector(setTitleTextAttributes:)])
   [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{
                         UITextAttributeFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12],
                    UITextAttributeTextColor:[UIColor redColor]
}];
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, it's `setFont` instead of `setTitleTextAttributes`

```
[[UILabel appearance] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"PT Sans Narrow" size:10.0]];
```